# How do I use autocrop in a function for catalog_apply()?

Tags: lidr

I would like to try the autocrop option, instead of crop inside the function, to resize output from catalog_apply() to the chunk size. In the code below, the commented-out code works, but the autocrop option doesn't.

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# How to crop raster chunks?
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(terra)
library(lidR)

ctgNorm <- readLAScatalog(system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR"))

ctgNorm@output_options$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite <- TRUE

makeCHM_function = function(chunk) {
  las = readLAS(chunk)
  if (is.empty(las))
    return(NULL)
  chm <- grid_canopy(las, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(0, 1.5), subcircle = 0.15))
  
  # Can I use AUTOCROP = TRUE in options below to replace the following 3 lines of code. 
  # I.e., crop to chunk extent.
  # rast(chm)
  # bbox <- lidR::extent(chunk)
  # chm  <- terra::crop(chm, bbox)
  
  return(chm)
}

opt_chunk_size(ctgNorm) <- 20
opt_chunk_buffer(ctgNorm) <- 2
opt_progress(ctgNorm) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(ctgNorm) <- "D:/Temp/chmNorm_tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"

# How do I use autocrop?
opt <- list(autocrop = TRUE)
myCHM <- catalog_apply(ctgNorm, makeCHM_function, .options = opt)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `catalog_map` in lidR v4.0.0 (Release date: 2022-02-17). With `catalog_map()` most classical use case are covered in a simple way. You not longer need to use `readLAS` or to crop anything this is automatically done internally.

```r
makeCHM_function = function(las) 
{
  chm <- grid_canopy(las, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(0, 1.5), subcircle = 0.15))
  return(chm)
}

opt_chunk_size(ctgNorm) <- 20
opt_chunk_buffer(ctgNorm) <- 2
opt_progress(ctgNorm) <- TRUE
opt_output_files(ctgNorm) <- "D:/Temp/chmNorm_tile_{XLEFT}_{YBOTTOM}"

myCHM <- catalog_map(ctgNorm, makeCHM_function)
```

---

That being said, I don't know if your example is a simplified exemple or your actual code. But in the later case you must know that the following works

```r
chm <- grid_canopy(ctgNorm, 1, pitfree(thresholds = c(0,2,5,10,15), max_edge = c(0, 1.5), subcircle = 0.15))
```

Comment: Yes it is a simplified code. In the actual function I've included a P2R CHM, and then filled in NAs with zero. Then used terra::cover to combine them. This deals with voids left in the Pitfree CHM due to my limiting the max edge c(3, 1.5), and voids where there is no data.

Comment: Also in the actual function, I use readLAS in the function - if it's empty or no veg hits, NULL is returned so catalog_apply doesn't process it. So catalog_map doesn't seem to handle that. I can post another question with the full code, or edit this one if it helps.

Comment: Ask another question